# AS3 receiving data from PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I cannot seem to take in Variable data, I appear to be doing everything right when consulting the Adobe AS3 References, I believe it is a problem with the PHP, but unsure.

PHP - This file is in the same directory as the AS3 doc

```
<?php

$testData = 4;

echo "testData=" . $testData

?>
```

AS3

```
public function URLLoaderDataFormatExample()
{
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("PHPTest.php");
    var variables:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    variables.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    variables.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    try
    {
        variables.load(request);
    } 
    catch (error:Error)
    {
        trace("Unable to load URL: " + error);
    }
}
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    trace(event.target.data.testData)
}
```

The trace statement should print 4. However, it just prints undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, I've already have to face that problem on my own too.

What I've discovered is that sometimes (didn't find the actual reason) the first value to be sent by the PHP gets nullified or even not sent at all.

I've been used to add an non-important value at the beginning of the echo, like :

```
echo 'unimportantvar=nothing&myXML='.$xml;
```

Always seemed to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it.

```
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loader.data);
    trace(urlVars.testData)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Actionscript code looks OK.

Flash is really sensitive to whitespace before/after the variables. Please note that if you have a new-line after the `?>`, or before the `<?php`, it will be given as part of the response.

To make sure that PHP is the problem, replace the .php file with a simple .txt, with just the text `testData=4`, with no additional new-lines or whitespace, and try to load that.

If this loads properly, the issue is with the PHP file - navigate to `PHPTest.php` in the browser and check if something gets inserted additionally.